# Loopback.io Multiple Include Model Query Conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

For a single model query, we can apply conditional operations on the conditions defined in a query, where the and/or operator is applied to the series of conditions:

```
{ where: {<and|or>: [condition1, condition2, ...]}}
```

Is there a neat way to apply conditional operations for the models included in **include**?

As an example:

```
Model.find({
    include: [
        {
            relation: "relation1",
            scope: {
                where: { condition1 }
            }
        },
         {
            relation: "relation2",
            scope: {
                where: { condition2 }
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to apply and/or operation on *condition1, condition2* above, i.e. return all models such that they match the conditions defined in the scope of the included models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do this as per this code example:

```
Post.find({
  include: {
    relation: 'owner', // include the owner object
    scope: { // further filter the owner object
      fields: ['username', 'email'], // only show two fields
      include: { // include orders for the owner
        relation: 'orders', 
        scope: {
          where: {orderId: 5} // only select order with id 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, function() { ... });
```

This is documented [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter) for the Include filter